# wget now automatically redirecting output to a log file, how to return back to putting output below

Tags: linux, wget

Whenever I used wget, the output and progress of the download would be displayed below.

I just tried using it today, and it only says 'Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.4’.'

Is there a way to bring it back to how it used to be?

Here's an example when I would run it in python 3

```
!pip install wget
!wget -i https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-research-public/open-corpus/corpus-2018-05-03/s2-corpus-01.gz
```

> Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.4’.

Comment: There is a similar report at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363765/why-do-i-keep-getting-wget-log-file-in-on-arch-linux from May 2017.

Answer (score 11):

This feature was introduced in `wget` v1.19 and is triggered under various circumstances. It is generally considered a bug, see [GNU Wget bug #51181: Unexpected "Redirecting output to 'wget-log'."](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51181). A reliable workaround is to add `-o /dev/null`.

Comment: I did include the " -o /dev/null" but it still says "redirecting output to 'wget-log.nn" My complete command is WGET_CMD="wget -O "+XMLFIL+" -o /dev/null --no-verbose --post-file="+ ...

Comment: To debug, run the command directly, not via a variable. Check the version, check that `-o file` is actually mentioned in `--help` and indeed writes log messages to file. If it does not consider a bug report.

Comment: My observation on wget v1.19.4 is that the -nv flag causes issues with the logging to output file. Remove that "-nv" or "--no-verbose" and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in the linux terminal. Try using `wget -q`

-q in the first flag, as in "quiet", not creating the wget-log file.

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue on wget version `1.21.1` but im using WSL, my solution is to just output the content of wget-log with `tail -f wget-log`

Comment: Works as a workaround, but some method of getting around the actual problem and having `wget` write to stdout would be much nicer (and is provided in an older comment)